# Additional online monolingual dictionaries?

Tags: soporte, recursos

I'm posting here as it was suggested at [Resources for learning Spanish / Recursos para aprender español](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23617/9385).

Sometimes I would like to consult a comprehensive online monolingual Spanish dictionary other than the DRAE.  I have not been able to find any.  Everything I've found is either bilingual or else it has a restricted word base.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Aparte del DRAE, yo diría que los otros que más uso son WordReference y [SpanishDict](https://www.spanishdict.com/dictionary)

Answer (score 6):

Pues me esperaba encontrar disponibles los más famosos, como el María Moliner o el de Seco, pero parece que no es tan fácil...

En [este sitio](http://www.diclib.com/cgi-bin/d.cgi?l=es&page=dicts) se puede consultar por índice el ***Diccionario de la lengua Alkona***, además de varios otros diccionarios técnicos de arquitectura, economía, náutica, etc., y las búsquedas se realizan sobre todos ellos al mismo tiempo.
Parece que antes también incluía el *Diccionario de uso del español* (María Moliner), pero a día de hoy no es así (ni he encontrado tampoco ningún sitio donde se pueda consultar este último).

En [este portal](https://www.diccionarios.com/) se pueden hacer búsquedas en línea usando los diccionarios de **VOX** y **Larousse**.

La [Universidad de Oviedo ofrece una lista de diccionarios](http://www6.uniovi.es/links/idiomas.html) de español de diferentes tipos (parece que ninguno es un diccionario completo como tal, sino más bien diccionarios de antónimos y cosas así, pero no me he metido a consultarlos todos).

El diccionario ***Clave***, de la editorial SM, se puede consultar en línea [aquí](http://clave.smdiccionarios.com/app.php).

La ***Enciclopedia Espasa*** tiene una [página que permite hacer búsquedas](http://espasa.planetasaber.com/), no sé si limitará el número de búsquedas o algo así, pero pinta bien.
Hablando de Espasa, el **diccionario de Espasa-Calpe** es el que se usa para la [búsqueda de palabras en WordReference](https://www.wordreference.com/definicion/) (gracias @blonfu).

El portal de **Wikilengua** ofrece una [lista de diccionarios](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Lista_de_diccionarios_en_Internet) disponibles para su consulta en Internet (incluye algunos de los ya mencionados).

Comment: Tambien está word reference que usa el diccionario Espasa Calpe 2005: https://www.wordreference.com/definicion/

Comment: Gracias.  Wow. // El primer enlace no me funciona.

Comment: Fantástico. Pues digo yo que todo esto se podría añadir a la pregunta de _Recursos..._

Comment: +6 en Meta solo se da en respuestas gran reserva, así que cuando quieras :P

Comment: a mí también me funciona el enlace

Comment: I get a 404.  I tried just www.diclib.com and got "We have started maintenance works. The site will be on-line soon. Please, visit this page in a couple of hours."   I tried this at 9:40 am Eastern time (Greenwich - 5).